# React, filepond and default files from url addresses

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file, filepond

I have a problem with set default files from url address.

My Filepond

```
            <FilePond
                files={[{
                    source:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tradeon-main.appspot.com/o/product_photos%2F5ba67faefe791907942c2d96%2Fc3e6c0bf-ec5f-25db-09ec-cfbe982498cd?alt=media&token=f9afc39b-5a2a-43d7-bf23-66b07919964e",
                    options: {
                        type: 'local'
                    }
                }]}
```

/>

I get following error "Size not available" which is rendered instead of image.
No errors in console.
I use react-filepond in version 7.1.1

It is bug or I do something bad?

Answer (score 0):

Because `type` is set to 'local' FilePond will try to use the `server.load` endpoint to load the file. Because `'local'` indicates that the file is on a local server and should be "restored" to the view.

More here: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#load

```
<FilePond
  server={{ 
    load: (src, load) => {
      // load file here and return file object to load
      fetch(src)
         .then(res => res.blob())
         .then(load);
    }
  }}
  files={[{
    source: 'your-local-file-id',
    options: {
      type: 'local'
    }
  }]}
/>
```